# Use hard-coded string or saving strings to external text file

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm coding a  mobile word guessing game. What are the best practices to saving short strings and sentences ? I'm going to have a definite amount of 300 words/sentences that I'm not going to change.

Is it better to save my strings inline hard coded like:

```
string[] words = { "Monday", "I am John.", "Computer", "...", "....", "..." };
```

Or should I create a MySQL database or an text file of some sort to save all the strings. Which is faster for mobile? What are your insights on this.
Thank you

Comment: You might give SQLite a try, especially if there is other data you need to persist on the device

Comment: Depending on the complexity of your project, using a simple text file with a key-value system may be enough (something like an [ini file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file)), and you will not bother with external libraries.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is probably the best way to go, you might also consider using Firebase - it offers a pretty decent database and other useful features for mobile development.

[Firebase website](https://firebase.google.com/)

[Adding Firebase to Unity](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup)

Comment: Deploying firebase might be a little "too much" in order to simply store strings. I see so much issues with Firebase, I would not advise this solution.

Answer (score 0):

In our project we've made a simple `TextAsset` inside `Resources` folder with all the localization text values in every line via:

```
----
HelloString
Hello
Привет
Halo
```

Make a static class or `DontDestroyOnLoad()` gameobject and read the file once in a script.

So when your game starts first, on the first `scene` (main menu scene) make a "loading" splash screen and simply read and parse this file with a script. When it finishes, remove the "loading" splach screen.

Then the whole strings data from this file will be stored in a static class and accessible in any code.

Easy, as it is.